# A general term for objects a user can interact with and how they are used

Tags: terminology

Is there a general term to describe objects that a user can interact with in a UI and how they are used by the user?

I'm writing a program which needs several types of UI and I'd like a way of naming functions which doesn't tie it down to one type in particular.

For example, in each of the UIs there should be a way of starting some tests running. If the only UI I was writing for was a {GUI / command line / voice command}, I'd use a name like {StartButtonPressed / StartOptionSelected / StartCommandGiven}, but I'd like a generic term to cover all UI types (or at least not tie it down to a single type).

The term should describe what event has happened, not what is required as a result of this event (e.g. StartRequested).

Any thoughts on what terminology to use for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, everything that happens because of user input is the result of a **command**. whether it is to create a new file, reorder the layout of a window or run a SQL query, whatever you like, those can all be named "commands" or a series of them. To give some examples:

- StartCreateFileCommand
- StartDragAndDropCommand
- StartExecuteSqlQueryCommand

etc.

Comment: Ideally I'd like it to be a passive phrase (used as an event name) rather than an active one, but command seems like a pretty good catch-all for the object name. I might go with something like **StartTestsCommandIssued** unless anyone else has a better idea.

Comment: In Java, there is the example of actionlisteners (action might be a replacement for command btw :)). It's an interface for AWT/Swing that tells when an **action** has been **performed**. Two terms you maybe want to use?

Comment: StartTestsActionPerformed does sound like a good option. The action required to start the tests was performed by the user. Sums it up nicely really :)

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck, and hopefully you won't encounter problems with that implementation :)